# What is a good way to rotate a pixel array?

Tags: c#, .net

Does the .NET framework provide a good way to rotate a pixel array?  To be more clear, I am not just looking for a way to rotate an image.  Instead I want to rotate the underlying pixel array that the image is/will be based on in such a way that I have access to the modified array.  I would rather not implement a rotation algorithm or wrap another library if the .NET framework already provides a good way to do this.  I need to be able to support any rotations, not merely 90/180/270/etc. rotations, which would be simple to implement.

I have thought about using one of the image classes that supports this type of rotation and accessing the modified array from it afterward.  I am not sure if this is a good idea in the first place and also not sure which image class would be the best choice for this.  So far I haven't had much luck finding a class or combination of classes that supports the rotations I need and enables access to the pixel array.

**Update:**

I'm starting to think I either asked the wrong question or asked the right question poorly.  If I understand what Cosmin meant about using the Matrix class correctly, I don't think this will work for what I am actually trying to do.  I'll try to do a better job of explaining my problem.

Basically, I have a 2D array of data and I want to rotate it.  What I mean by this is that I want the values of the elements to be rotated to the appropriate elements based on the rotation.

For example:

```
-----------
|A|A|A|A|A|
-----------
|B|B|B|B|B|
-----------
|C|C|C|C|C|
-----------
```

If I were to rotate this array around the center element by 90 degrees counterclockwise, I should end up with something like this:

```
-----------
| |A|B|C| |
-----------
| |A|B|C| |
-----------
| |A|B|C| |
-----------
```

Unfortunately, I have to support any rotation, not just 90 degree rotations, which means a more complicated rotation algorithm is needed, since the rotated element indexes won't always be integers and may overlap as well.  This seems like a problem that has probably been solved in the field of computer graphics, which led to me ask the question the way I did.

Comment: Why do you need access to the pixel array?

Comment: I thought about including this in my original post, but felt there was a good chance that it would lead to off-topic/misguided answers to my question.  I may have been wrong.  Basically, I am presenting multiple views of this data, one of which is an ASCII view.  The data is geographic in nature and I need to provide the user with views oriented in a certain way, so I need to rotate the data before trying to represent it as an ASCII image.

Comment: Maybe specifying a pixel array was a bad idea, since if I could rotate any 2D array by an arbitrary angle, this would probably solve my problem.  Seems most likely that such an algorithm is going to be related to computer graphics though, which led me to ask the question the way I did.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the Matrix class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.aspx